# Why is empty disk reporting significant usage?

Tags: hard-disk, ext4, data-recovery

Let me start off by saying that I’m well aware of the difference between **B** and **iB** and this is **not** a discrepancy involving terminology as it does not relate to total disk space but space **used** on the disk compared to space **available** on the disk, both in the same measurement system.

Now that that is out of the way, I have a hard drive reporting with `df -h` a total size of 4.6T and only 12K of used space, yet it also says there is only 4.3T of available space. I’m no mathematician but last time I checked 12K =/= 300G… How do I find this “ghost data” and remove it from my drive? I’ve had my server offline for like two days because of this.

I’ve already tried `lsof /path/to/drive | grep deleted` but that didn’t help. I’ve also tried `shred` and `Diskpart> clean /all` (windows) reformatting as ext4 and using `fsck` after every thing but nothing seems to get rid of it.

Comment: Formal note: there's no such thing as `iB`. In `MiB` the `i` belongs to the `Mi` prefix.

Comment: reserved space on ext4 is 5%, that is about 230G in your case...

Comment: Reserved for what/who? Why is it reserved? What file system should I use that won’t steal all my space?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110332 - you can decrease the reserved space if you so wish although it's usually advised against

Comment: Well I’d say that pretty much solves it. I don’t see an option to add a check next to your answer though.

Comment: Not sure of the details of ext4, but typically: root user is told the available size without the reserved blocks; space for inodes is reserved separately; space is used by the free space mapping.