# Why does df show Available 0 when 1K-blocks minus Used is greater than 0?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, ext3

Why does it show 0 in the available column?

```
[root@server log]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              4128448   4096484         0 100% /
```

It's an ext3 filesystem.

Comment: <rant> Just because a question is covered by a broad other question doesn't make my specific question a dupe.  If that were true, then we wouldn't need specific laws -- just one "Be nice to people".

Comment: I quote: "*when I add the “Used” and “Available” columns of df, I don't get the total figure*". That is exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This information has been covered multiple times before; see [What happened to my free space?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2827/80216) and [Why is (free_space + used_space) != total_size in df?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25602/80216)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`df` reports the percentage of used blocks relative to the blocks not reserved for root use (by default I think it's 5% of the drive in ext3). It can be changed by using the `-m` option of `tune2fs` e.g. to set it to 2%

```
tune2fs -m 2 /dev/sdXY
```

The reserved blocks allow system daemons to keep going even when the disk is full, while non-root processes will not be able to write to it. It also helps reducing drive fragmentation.