# GPT Partition - Used Space immediately after creating partition

Tags: partition, gpt

I wanted to try out the new GPT system, and used it to partition my new HDD, with the partitions themselves using ext4. For some reason, about 1-2% of the space in each partition is already shown as used, both in `df` and `gparted`. Currently the only content of the partitions is the lost+found folder which occupies all of `16K`.

Is there a reason for this? Can this be fixed? Or is this just the space used by the file table (or equivalent)?

Edit: Is this more related ext4 than GPT? I found this just now, [ext4: How to account for the filesystem space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space)

Comment: Perhaps tune2fs is what you're looking for, especially the -m flag.

Comment: or of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space/13551#13551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-5% is reserved for root and as overhead for the filesystem.  It is NORMAL. This is done is to leave root that 1-5% so if the users on the machine fill the disk up, critical system processes and the root user still have a small chunk to play with.  As jordanm pointed out, the reserved space is also used to reduce filesystem fragmentation.

You can use `tune2fs -m 1.0 /dev/sda2` to lower the default 5% to 1%. Please note that it is not recommended to use `-m 0` but still can be done.

Comment: I think you are mixing up things. The *reserved* space is proper disk space reserved to the UID 0, whereas the file system structures are meta-data and not normally shown.

Comment: Was in the process of editing my answer, thanks though.

Comment: The reserved space is also used to reduce fragmentation.