# How can I find the last sector used by an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: ext4

I need to identify the last sector used by an ext4 filesystem so that I can move it to another device.

The filesystem has been shrunk (with `resize2fs`) and is smaller than the partition that contains it, so I am not asking how to find the last sector in the partition.

I have done `tune2fs -l` and identified that

```
Block count:              48934
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
```

From that I would postulate that the filesystem uses 48934 * 4096 / 512 = 391472 sectors and that I can move that many sectors with `dd` starting at the first sector of the partition (as reported by `gdisk`).

I am uncertain whether that block count includes any ext4 overhead or if there is additional size that needs to be considered. I read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space) which implies there is additional space to be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. There shouldn't be any problem.

To avoid some calculations you could use the `bs` option and use the partition name of the device rather than starting at an offset.

```
dd count=48934 bs=4096 if=/dev/sdxN  of=...
```

To be 100% sure about the size you could test it before. "Simulate" a smaller partition:

```
umount /dev/XYZ
losetup --offset N-BYTES --sizelimit $(( 48934 * 4096 )) /dev/loop1 /dev/XYZ
```

`mount` or `fsck` of `/dev/loop1` should tell you if you made it too small. `resize2fs` would tell if the partition is still too large but there is no `dry-run`. You could also play around with `fsadm -v --dry-run check/resize ...` which I have never used yet. If paranoid you should use `losetup --read-only`. Don't forget `losetup --detach` when done.

Comment: That's great, Yes I actually used `dd if=/dev/sdd2 of=/dev/sdc5 bs=512 count=395568` (It's LUKS and I also copied the LUKS header). So far, so good.

Comment: I've updated the "testing before" part. Should be also useful somehow in LUKS case.

Comment: @starfry [Don't use `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days). Do the loopback mount and use `cat`, it's the easiest way to ensure you're copying the right thing, and it's faster.

Comment: @Gilles, why would `cat` be faster than `dd` with a `lo`-device?

Comment: @TomHale I don't know. It may not always be faster, but I did find that it was faster in [a benchmark](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492), even when varying the `dd` block size, and more so with `dd`'s default tiny block size.