# Disk usage confusion: 10G missing on Linux home partition on SSD

Tags: linux, disk-usage, ssd

Linux Mint tells me, I only have 622 MB free disk space but there should be some gigabytes left.

Looking at the partitions I am told that there are about ten gigabytes unused. I googled the problem and didn't find a solution but I did find the hint that I should check the disk usage with `df -h`.

```
sudo df -h /home
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p8  189G  178G  622M 100% /home
```

The output doesn't make any sense to me: The difference between `Size` and `Used` is 11GB, but it only shows `622M` as Available.

The SSD isn't old, so I wouldn't expect such a discrepancy.

What should I do?

Comment: as @Kusalananda commented, you shouldn't just question why you don't get those 10GB (which I hope I addressed correctly in my answer), but also why you're using most of the space in /home. If you know why (eg: store a lot of media files etc.) that's fine, if you don't, you should worry about it, with potential cleaning giving back more than 10GB of space savings. So what would it be?

Comment: “Looking at the partitions I am told that there are about ten gigabytes unused.” — where were you told this?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor from `df`'s output – Size: 189G, Used: 178G

Comment: @ctrl-alt delor, I got the figure 10GB from gparted – and later 11G from df's output, as billyjmc correctly inferred.

Comment: @A.B thank you for your answer. I know what's using up the space. I just had the impression that I suddenly had a few gigabytes less than I expected. When I investigated this, I got worried because 10 gigabytes couldn't be used. But you cleared that up for me. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ext4: How to account for the filesystem space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the filesystem is ext4, there are reserved blocks, mostly to help handling and help avoid fragmentation and available only to the root user. For this setting, it can be changed live using *[tune2fs](https://manpages.debian.org/e2fsprogs/tune2fs.8)* (not all settings can be handled like this when the filesystem is mounted):

> -m reserved-blocks-percentage
>
> Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged processes. Reserving some number of filesystem blocks
>   for use by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem
>   fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to
>   continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are
>   prevented from writing to the filesystem. Normally, the default
>   percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

So if you want to lower the reservation to 1% (~ 2GB) thus getting access to ~ 8GB of no more reserved space, you can do this:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/nvme0n1p8
```

Note: the `-m` option actually accepts a decimal number as parameter. You can use `-m 0.1` to reserve only about ~200MB (and access most of those previously unavailable 10GB). You can also use the `-r` option instead to reserve directly by blocks. It's probably not advised to have 0 reserved blocks.

Comment: The user is not "getting back" 8 GB. The are getting 8 GB more to spend. It would be better to track down what's using up all the disk space and then possibly do a cleanup of that, if appropriate, or otherwise move it elsewhere, or grow the partition.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'll change the vocabulary. As for the usage, I'd need OP's feedback. The question never hinted that there was unknown high usage, only missing 10GB.

Comment: A very good and helpful answer, thank you. 5% seems to match the missing 10 gigabytes very clearly.
I am not worried about using so much disk space overall, and I can still grow my partition. :)

Comment: Your answer is certainly correct, but it may be worth noting that the value of root-reserved space in this case isn't huge. This is `/home`, and reserving space for root  there isn't as important as it is for other parts of the file system (e.g. to ensure system logs can still be written). Also, as this is an SSD, preventing fragmentation may not have the priority it does on spinning metal disks.

Comment: @marcelm That makes sense to me. But is it still useful on a /home partition on an SSD or is it just a waste of space?
Would you recommend lowering the root reserved space to 1%?

Answer (score 10):

Deleted files can also contribute to "missing space"

```
lsof | grep deleted | grep /home
```

returns this output for me

```
chrome    11181           criggie   15u      REG              254,0   
4194304  50651663 /home/criggie/.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-5D0236AF-2BAD.pma (deleted)
```

Which shows that Chrome running as PID 11181 opened that BrowserMetrics file then deleted it, and still has the filehandle open.  This means the file is invisible in a directory listing, but is still taking up disk space.

Why do programmes do this?  When the running binary terminates, the OS will release the open file handle and the file on disk will be gone, without risk of leaving a stale temp-file around.

What I can't see is how big that file's disk usage is.

Comment: Most *well-written* programs should not do this. It's a bug, and should be reported, it's just that most of these obscure bugs don't really show up until you are in an optimization phase, and if it's a one off it may even not really be detected at all during testing. Note that there may be a specific reason why they are doing this, there may be a rationale I am not aware of here for keeping the handle open this long.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey Dude - its Chrome... you're totally correct.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey, a great many *well-written* programs do this.  The open-delete-close pattern for creating temporary files on \*nix is nearly universal, because it guarantees the file will be deleted when the program exits, regardless of *how* it exits: normal termination, crashing, killed by running out of memory, killed by power failure, etc.

Comment: This doesn't account for the discrepancy seen using `df` (which simply counts used blocks, and takes no account of link count or anything to do with names)

Comment: Open-delete-close is fine, what is wrong is open-delete and then keep the handle open until the process terminates. This is NOT normal behavior for any program. A handle should be freed as soon as the program is done with it.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey so, what if the program is _never_ done with it?

Comment: Hence why I specified there may be a rationale for keeping it open in my first comment, but if there is it should be clearly defined.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey: The pattern is open-delete-*work*-close. If the program is still doing something with the contents of the temporary file (e.g. using it as an on-disk cache, or logging telemetry data into it), then of course it must keep it open. (Of course, it's also possible that this is indeed a stale unclosed file handle that the program should've closed but didn't. But given that there's only one such file, and that there are no other obvious indications of a resource leak, I would start with the assumption that the file is probably being kept open on purpose.)