# Partition Size and df output differ

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk-usage

When I run "df -h", I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.5G   12K  2.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           509M  896K  508M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        38G   33G  2.5G  94% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.5G   84K  2.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
none            298G  206G   93G  69% /media/sf_share
```

On /dev/sda1, the difference between size and used is 5G, but available is only 2.5G.

I just deleted a lot of files, but when I filled it up to 100%, I went into GParted and I could see that /dev/sda1 still had white space for this partition.

sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda results in:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    79249407    39623680   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        79249408    90111999     5431296    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        79251456    90111999     5430272   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 gives me:

```
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 9905920 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: @Gilles, it's nota  duplicate of "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/why-are-partition-size-and-df-output-different?s=2|1.4734".  Their use of "fdisk" got them new space, but didn't work for me.

Comment: What made you think that it's a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/why-are-partition-size-and-df-output-different ? That's not where the duplicate link points to. But the most-upvoted answer in that thread gives the answer for your case too: there's a 5% reserve for root.

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks.  As far as this issue goes: "I went into GParted and I could see that /dev/sda1 still had white space for this partition", the problem was that I needed to boot into GParted LiveCD as described in http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/  otherwise if I booted into my hard disk, I could only increase the partition size, not shrink it.